# Gnome Shell Extensions not downloading

Tags: 20.04, firefox, gnome-shell-extension

I'm trying to install Gnome Shell extensions from the Firefox plugin at Ubuntu 20.04. I followed all steps as described by [this guide](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-gnome-shell-extensions-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux-desktop), but when I switch the install button to "on", nothing happens. The "download and install" window (as in step 10 of this guide) does not show and when I reload the page, the button says "off" again.

I have installed `gnome-shell-extensions`, `chrome-gnome-shell` and the Shell-Integration Firefox plugin. I have also re-logged in my session. Extensions are activated in the Tweaks and the Extensions Settings menu. I have tried several extensions. Any ideas what could prevent the "download and install" window to show up? Could it be related to the proxy I have to use to connect to the internet?

Comment: Can you try with another browser, e.g. Chrome, and see if it works with it?

Comment: In Chromium Browser Gnome Shell Extension shows the following error message: "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector." These instructions tell me to install `chrome-gnome-shell`, which I did.

Comment: Chromium is a snap in 20.04 and it might not work with `chrome-gnome-shell` (I haven't tested it, so I'm not sure if that's the case). Can you try with Chrome?

Comment: I installed chrome as .deb from dl.google.com but I have the same behavior there.

Comment: Are you using an ad blocker? Perhaps this is what prevents the pop up from showing. Please disable the ad blocker, if you use one, and try again.

Comment: Good point, that was also my first intention. I have disabled it and it didn't change anything. Moreover, I didn't install any adblocker on chromium/chrome at all and it didn't show up, too.

Comment: I now also tried to start Firefox in debug mode (firefox -g and then run) but after firefox is up, there are no more messages displayed. Is there any other way to set firefox to something like "verbose" or a log file?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I hope that another user will be of more help.